# Covariance matrix from GJR-GARCH?

Tags: garch, covariance, covariance-matrix

I am implementing a AR(1)-GJR-GARCH(1,1) model to some asset returns, and I would need to have a covariance matrix but I struggle to see how I can compute one from the model I used?
I know I can have a volatility estimate with a GARCH model, but what about covariance?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a multivariate Garch indeed. Search for mGARCH versions like GARCH-BEKK or VECH GARCH or DCC.